# Type error: Argument 1 passed Chat::__construc t() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, websocket

I working on a web socket app using ratchet and symfony 2.8 to connect to database and changing value in a certain column if someone connect to the server so I should injection the service and add the  `EntityManager $em`
to `function __construct()` like that but the problem is when i adding it like that on `Chat.php` file

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
```

I get this error

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                      
  Type error: Argument 1 passed Chat::__construc t() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in SocketCommand.php on line 41
```

this error tell me there are a problem on file `SocketCommand.php` on this line

```
new Chat()
```

the chat.php file

```
<?php
namespace check\roomsBundle\Sockets;
use tuto\testBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface  {
    //private $container;
    protected $clients;
    protected $em;
    //protected $db;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        //$this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
        //$this->em->getRepository('yorrepo')->updateFuntion();
        $sql = $this->container->get('database_connection');
        $users = $sql->query("UPDATE user SET ONoroff= '1999' WHERE UserId='2'");


    }
}
```

the SocketCommand.php code

```
<?php
// myapplication/src/sandboxBundle/Command/SocketCommand.php
// Change the namespace according to your bundle
namespace check\roomsBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

// Include ratchet libs
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

// Change the namespace according to your bundle
use check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat;

class SocketCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('sockets:start-chat')
            // the short description shown while running "php bin/console list"
            ->setHelp("Starts the chat socket demo")
            // the full command description shown when running the command with
            ->setDescription('Starts the chat socket demo')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln([
            'Chat socket',// A line
            '============',// Another line
            'Starting chat, open your browser.',// Empty line
        ]);

        $server = IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    new Chat()
                )
            ),
            8080
        );

        $server->run();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the third time you have asked the same question in the last two days.  Each with the exact same answer.  Take a moment to read the chapter on dependency injection.  Keep in mind the new'ing has nothing to do with the Symfony container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you've defined the constructor as:

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    //$this->container = $container;
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

So then you'll need to get an entity manager something like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

and then pass this in when you create your new object like so:

```
new Chat( $em )
```

So you'll need to figure out how to do that.

Comment: i get   Notice: Undefined variable: em

Comment: Your `SocketCommand` class extends command, so I don't think you can get an EntityManager the same way. Take a look [at this documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#obtaining-an-entitymanager), I'm not sure if that will work for you. Regardless, my response does answer your question as to why you are getting the error, and you should mark it as correct. If you have another question, you should post a different question.